# crossreferencing pandas dataframe in apply

Tags: python, pandas, apply

So I have some data like:

```
a.csv:

id, ..., name
1234, ..., R
1235, ..., Python
1236, ..., Panda
... etc

b.csv:

id, ..., amount
1234, ..., 1
1234, ..., 1
1234, ..., 2
...
1236, ..., 1
1236, ..., 1
```

I am trying to cross-reference the IDs between a.csv and b.csv in order to add a quantity column to my pandas dataframe for a.csv. This quantity is "the sum of amounts in b.csv for the matching ID of this row".

I'm trying to use the apply function like so:

```
  import pandas as pd
  def itemcounts(row):
      # ok this works?
      # return b[b['id'] == 1234]['amount'].sum()
      # each a['quantity'] gets set to 4 or whatever the sum for 1234 is.

      # and this does?
      # return row['id']
      # a['quantity'] get set to whatever row's 'id' is.

      # but this doesn't
      id = row['id']
      return b[b['id'] == id]['amount'].sum()
      # a['quantity'] is 0.

  a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
  b = pd.read_csv('b.csv')
  a['quantity'] = a.apply(itemcounts, axis=1)
```

But as noted in the comments I can't get apply to find the matching rows in `b` to get the sum. I expect I am missing something fundamental to python or pandas here.

I tried casting the `row['id']` to int in itemcounts but that still did not work out for me.

Comment: Does it have to use `apply`? I have a solution that doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. It turns out I was a victim of dirty data. Both  files were about 1000 lines, but the ID's did not actually align for all cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

a['Quantity'] = a['id'].apply(lambda x: b[b.id == x].amount.sum())
```

Using the "lambda" in the apply function allows you to use apply each row of a column into a function as "x".

Taking a:

```
    id    name
0  1234       r        
1  1235  Python       
2  1236   Panda
```

and b:

```
     id  amount   
0  1234       1
1  1234       1
2  1234       2
3  1236       1
4  1236       1
```

It returns:

```
        id    name  Quantity
0     1234       r         4
1     1235  Python         0
2     1236   Panda         2
```

Comment: Hey thanks, as it turns out both my solution and yours work. My issue was that a.csv has 1000 rows and b.csv has 1000 rows, but for every row in a.csv we have 1 ID, whereas each ID might have 200 rows in b.csv. So of course when I saw "quantity: 0" for all my (visible) results, I assumed I was dumb and not my data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1234, 1235, 1236], 'name' : ['R', 'Python', 'Pandas']})

     id    name
0  1234       R
1  1235  Python
2  1236  Pandas

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1235, 1235, 1236], 'amount' : [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]})

   amount    id
0       1  1234
1       1  1234
2       2  1234
3       1  1234
4       2  1234
5       2  1235
6       1  1235
7       1  1236

df['quantity'] = df1.groupby('id').agg(sum).values

     id    name  quantity
0  1234       R         7
1  1235  Python         3
2  1236  Pandas         1
```

Comment: This solution gave me "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" because as I noted above, my data was dirty.

Comment: This was very valuable in determining the problem thank you